# Обернуть контент между двух независимых тегов в другой тег

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок с текстом и тегами. И есть в нем две метки span с id. Они могут быть как и в общем теге "p" так и в различных тегах как указано ниже.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="text">
     <p>Тест <span id="mr-1"></span> loremipsum</p>
     <p>парам парам парам пам пам <span id="mr-2"></span></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите плиз как можно обернуть, исходя из этих меток текст который между ними, в тег "i":

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="text">
     <p>Тест <i><span id="mr-1"></span>loremipsum</i></p>
     // or
     <p>Тест <span id="mr-1"></span><i>loremipsum</i></p>

     <p><i>парам парам парам пам пам <span id="mr-2"></span></i></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

И в случаи если общий родитель:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="text">
     <p>Тест <i><span id="mr-1"></span> loremipsum <span id="mr-2"></span></i></p>
     // or
     <p>Тест <span id="mr-1"></span> <i>loremipsum</i> <span id="mr-2"></span></p>

     <p>парам парам парам пам пам</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
$(_ => {
  let isWrap = false;
  $('.wrapper').find(":not(iframe)").addBack().contents().each((i, e) => {
    let $e = $(e);
    
    isWrap ? $e.wrap('<i></i>') : null;
    
    if(e.nodeType === 1){
      if($e.attr('id') === 'mr-1') isWrap = true;
      if($e.attr('id') === 'mr-2') isWrap = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="text">
     <p>Тест <span id="mr-1"></span> loremipsum</p>
     <p>парам парам парам пам пам <span id="mr-2"></span> text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да. Спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 0):

```js
wrapWith('.wrapper', '<i class="test">', '</i>'); 

function wrapWith(parentsSelector, opnTag, clsTag) {
  const RE = /(id="mr-1">\s*<\/span>)([\s\S]+?)(<span id="mr-2")/gmi; 
  let parentEls = document.querySelectorAll(parentsSelector);
  for (let el of parentEls) 
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(RE, `\$1${opnTag}\$2${clsTag}\$3`); 
}
```

```css
.wrapper   { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
.wrapper p { margin: 0.15em 0; }
i.test     { color: #080; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Тест <span id="mr-1"></span> lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>парам парам парам пам пам <span id="mr-2"></span></p>
    <p>dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Тест <span id="mr-1"></span> lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>парам парам парам пам пам <span id="mr-2"></span></p>
    <p>dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```